# How to remove/unsubscribe listener from data table using YUI

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I did subscribe an event on data table as follows ([YUI data table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/#cellediting)):

`myDataTable.subscribe("cellClickEvent", this.myDataTable.onEventShowCellEditor);`

how can I achieve as follows?

```
If (condition)
   show cell editor 
else 
  remove or hide cell editor
```

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: You should add more code to your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onEventShowCellEditor is nothing really special, it simply calls method showCellEditor.  So can you.  Instead of setting a listener for the event and pass it straight through to onEventShowCellEditor put your own listener there instead and decide prior to calling showCellEditor:

```
myDataTable.subscribe('cellClickEvent', function (oArgs) {
   if (condition) {
        myDataTable.showCellEditor(oArgs.target);
   } else {
...whatever
   }
});
```